# Play two videos at the same time in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, html5-video

I'm trying to play two videos side by side in `HTML`, at the same time, preferrably by one control, as if they are a single video (one is a filtered version of the other, that's why).

How can I achieve that?

Here is the simple code I have so far that plays them separately, but side by side:

```
<center>
<video height="350" controls>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<video height="350" controls>
  <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</center>
```

Comment: Is this solved? You could try... **(1)** Give each video an ID then have a `<button>` that tells both players (via Javascript) to play. **(2)** A more advanced solution is to use the known FPS of **video1** to seek frame-by-frame in both video tags. There will be no sound though (since you are seeking into paused frames). **(3)** Hire somebody because this is an unusual feature (a far as normal video playback is concerned).

Comment: Not really. I finally created a stacked video and just play it.

Answer (score 2):

You can stream from one media element to another. It should be pretty instantaneous. But then again, it would be the same source.

```js
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2016 The WebRTC project authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
 *  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
 *  tree.
 */
'use strict';

const leftVideo = document.getElementById('leftVideo');
const rightVideo = document.getElementById('rightVideo');

leftVideo.addEventListener('play', () => {
  let stream;
  const fps = 0;
  if (leftVideo.captureStream) {
    stream = leftVideo.captureStream(fps);
  } else if (leftVideo.mozCaptureStream) {
    stream = leftVideo.mozCaptureStream(fps);
  } else {
    console.error('Stream capture is not supported');
    stream = null;
  }
  rightVideo.srcObject = stream;
  rightVideo.play()
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<video id="leftVideo" height="350" controls crossorigin="anonymous">
  <source  src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
<video id="rightVideo" height="350" controls crossorigin="anonymous">

</video>
```

Comment: Does it play one audio or both at the same time?

Comment: it streams both audio and video. whether it plays audio together on same page? I don't know. maybe if we play 10 together and it sounds louder then we could tell

Comment: Yeah generally we would just need audio from one and mute the rest.

Comment: Btw, where should I insert these webrtc code in? Is it inside `<script type="text/javascript">` ? Also, I have two DIFFERENT videos. I see only one source is defined in your answer.